# Enumerating DLL functions?

Tags: c#, dll, function, enums, dllimport

Is it possible to enumerate every function present in a DLL ? How about getting its signature ?
Can I do this in C# ? Or do I have to go low level to do this?

Regards and tks,
Jose

Comment: Are you talking about unmananged or managed DLLs?

Comment: I'm trying to it programmaticaly at runtime, they can be unmanaged or managed

Comment: I added an edit to my answer based on you needing to load the objects at runtime.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it's a .NET DLL [RedGate's Reflector](http://www.red-gate.com/products/reflector/index.htm) can list the methods and even attempt to disassemble the code.  It's a great item for any developer's toolbox and it's free

**Edit:** If you are trying to read the types and methods at runtime you'll want to use Reflection.  You would have to load the `Assembly` and `GetExportedTypes`.  Then, iterate over the `Members` to the the `Methods` and `Properties`.  Here is an article from MSDN that has an example of iterating over the [`MemberInfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.memberinfo.aspx) information. Also, here is an MSDN Magazine article, [Extracting Data from .NET Assemblies](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc164006.aspx).

Finally, Here is a little test method I wrote for executing a method on a loaded object.

In this example ClassLibrary1 has one class of Class1:

```
public class Class1
{
    public bool WasWorkDone { get; set; }

    public void DoWork()
    {
        WasWorkDone = true;
    }
}
```

And here is the test:

```
[TestMethod]
public void CanExecute_On_LoadedClass1()
{
    // Load Assembly and Types
    var assm = Assembly.LoadFile(@"C:\Lib\ClassLibrary1.dll");
    var types = assm.GetExportedTypes();

    // Get object type informaiton
    var class1 = types.FirstOrDefault(t => t.Name == "Class1");
    Assert.IsNotNull(class1);

    var wasWorkDone = class1.GetProperty("WasWorkDone");
    Assert.IsNotNull(wasWorkDone);

    var doWork = class1.GetMethod("DoWork");
    Assert.IsNotNull(doWork);

    // Create Object
    var class1Instance = Activator.CreateInstance(class1.UnderlyingSystemType);

    // Do Work
    bool wasDoneBeforeInvoking = 
          (bool)wasWorkDone.GetValue(class1Instance, null);
    doWork.Invoke(class1Instance, null);
    bool wasDoneAfterInvoking = 
          (bool)wasWorkDone.GetValue(class1Instance, null);

    // Assert
    Assert.IsFalse(wasDoneBeforeInvoking);
    Assert.IsTrue(wasDoneAfterInvoking);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If its a managed dll: Use reflection

If its unmanaged: You need to enumerate the DLL export table

Answer (score 1):

You can see all of the exports in a dll by using Dependency Walker, which is a free program from Microsoft: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_walker

Answer (score 1):

For regular win32 DLLs, see [the Dumpbin utility](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/177429). It is included with Visual-C++ (including the free "express" version I believe).

example:

```
c:\vc9\bin\dumpbin.exe /exports c:\windows\system32\kernel32.dll
```